# Openshift: oc client inside a container

Tags: openshift

I need to use `oc` client inside a container in order to create secrets.

I've took a look over internet in order to look up which image might I use in order to use `oc`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [openshift3/ose-client](https://catalog.redhat.com/software/containers/openshift3/ose-cli/5b52388cd70cc556394911f9) for OpenShift 3 and the [openshift4/ose-client](https://catalog.redhat.com/software/containers/openshift4/ose-cli/5cd9ba3f5a13467289f4d51d) image for OpenShift 4 platforms. Both images should be available from Red Hat from inside your cluster.

Answer (score 1):

As I remember, the following builder images were installed oc client (atomic-openshift-clients package)

- S2i builder image

https://access.redhat.com/containers/?tab=package-list#/registry.access.redhat.com/openshift3/ose-sti-builder/images/v3.9.25-1

- Docker builder image

https://access.redhat.com/containers/?tab=package-list#/registry.access.redhat.com/openshift3/ose-docker-builder/images/v3.9.30-2